# Prove $\sin{x}\neq 2x$ for any $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, trigonometry, contest-math

I have to show that
$$\sin{x}=2x\ for\ some\ x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$$
is wrong.
I have used *Intermediate Value Theorem* and failed to disprove.

Let $f(x)=\sin x-2x$
$f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=1-\pi=-2.14$

Hence there is an x for which $f(x)=0$

i.e $\sin x-2x=0$, $\sin x=x$ for some $x\in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$

It's clearly visible while using graphical methods, but I cannot prove theoretically.

[image]

This question was part of a mock test in functions and analysis, for postgraduate entrance exam. I am just starting to learn higher mathematics.
Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: Note that $f(x) = 2x - \sin x$ implies that $f'(x) = 2 - \cos x > 0$ for all $x$ and so $f$ is increasing. Therefore since $f(0) = 0$, it must be that $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: To fill in some details of Gregory's comment, we know that $f$ passes $(0,0)$, and if it were to have a positive root, it would pass $(b,0)$ also. By the MVT (the assumptions of which are satisfied), the secant line between these two points (which is parallel [moreover coincident] to the $x$-axis) should be parallel to a tangent to $f$ at some $0<c<b$. But then $f'(c)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intermediate value theorem can tell you when a solution *does* exist but it can't tell you when a solution doesn't exist (It also isn't fool-proof; a solution may exist but you missed it by testing intervals too wide).

The derivative can tell you when a function is increasing decreasing and that can be a helpful tool.  If $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ and $f(a) > 0$ then there can't be any solutions for example.

If $f(x) = \sin x - 2x$ then $f'(x) = \cos x - 2\le 1-2 < 0$ so $f(x)$ is always decreasing.  $f(0) = \sin 0 - 2\times 0 =0$ but $f(x)$ is *always* decreasing.  So we have $f(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$ and so $\sin x -2x < 0$ and $\sin x < 2x$ for all $x > 0$.  (Likewise $f(x) > 0$ for all $x < 0$ so $\sin x > 2x$ for all $x < 0$.

....

Now you *should* have been able to solve with intermediate value theorem.

If we did the above we'd also find $\cos x - 2x$ is always decreasing but as $\cos 0 = 1$ and $2\cdot 0 = 0$ So $\cos x - 2x = 1 > 0$ and $\cos x-2x$ is decreasing so it's possible that $\cos x - 2x =0$ for some $x > 0$ (but not for any $x < 0$ and there can be at most one solution.

Anyhoo.   $\cos 0 -2\cdot =1> 0$ and $\cos \frac \pi 2 - 2\cdot \frac \pi 2= 0-\pi =-\pi < 0$.  So there must be some value between $0$ and $\frac \pi 2$ where $\cos x - 2x = 0$ and $\cos x = 2x$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x > 0$, we have
$ 2x > x > \sin x $. Hence the first equation does not have a solution. 
This can be proved.

Let's consider: $g(x) = 2x-\sin x \implies g'(x) = 2 - \cos x $ 
$g(0)=0$ and $g'(x)>0$ for all $x \in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$

$g'(x)>0$ means that the function is strictly increasing. 
That is, for all $k \in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)$, we have: 
$g(k)>g(0)$, that is, $g(k)>0$, or $2k > \sin k$

For the other one, consider $f(x) = 2x - \cos x$ 
Then, $f(0) = -1$, and $f(\pi/2) = \pi$; hence by intermediate value theorem, we have 
$\exists c \in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) \hspace{5pt}  f(c)=0$, i.e. $2c = \cos c$

Comment: "For all x>0, we have 2x>x>sinx."  I don't think the OP knows that and that is precisely what is being asked to prove.

Comment: @fleablood you maybe right, I was just trying to avoid using derivatives.

Comment: @fleablood you maybe right, I was just trying to avoid using derivatives.

Comment: What does it mean when g'(x)>0? How is that the answer to my problem? Forgive me if I'm being stupid

Comment: @Mathboi I have added that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the difference between $\sin x$ and $x$, consider the function

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}{x}& (x \ne 0)\\0 & (x=0)\end{cases}$$

which is a very famous $C^{\infty}$ function called "cardinal sine" or ["sinc" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function)

Its absolute value is $\le 1$ therefore $2$ is never reached !

Comment: If i use this in the proof, then I have to prove that it's absolute value is $\leq 1$...